# Run a Script after a Backlog Transition in TFS 2018

Tags: tfs

I am working with TFS 2018.
I have a project in which I have some backlog Items. In my board I have the states: Proposed, Active, Resolved and closed.

[image]

I want to be able to run a script after an Item moves from the Active State to Resolved state.

Can you help me with this? How can I achieve that?

PS: I'd like to create new branches automatically and build pipelines and Also  move a work Item to a given state and delete that branch afterwards? This is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

TFS does not support any internal triggers or automation script. But you may write your own based on [Web Hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops). There is additional server plugins like [TFS Aggregator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tfsaggregatorteam.tfs-aggregator-server-plugin).

Comment: But I believe it was supported in TFS 2015. Can you confirm it? My team had it working in TFS 2015.

Comment: TFS 2015 also supports only: 1. Server plugins like TFS Aggregator; 2. Notifications to a Soap service; 3. Custom user control for work item forms. We used to create a soap service that runs powershell script or custom c# console project to process notifications.

Comment: Ok, can you confirm if TFS 2018 API has changed from the one existing in TFS 2015?

Comment: Also, for TFS 2018 do you have any idea of how to do those automations?

Comment: Do you know if TFS Agregator has the abiltiy to create new branches and build pipelines? Also can it move a work Item to a given state and delete that branch afterwards? This is what I am looking for.

Comment: No the TFS aggregator currently is limited to Work Items to prevent people from shooting themselves in the foot. You can create a custom service hook receiver to do your automation.

Comment: I know TFS Net Api will be deprecated soon [Announcing the deprecation of the WIT and Test Client](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/announcing-the-deprecation-of-the-wit-and-test-client-om-at-jan-1-2020-2/). TFS Aggregator has documentation for work items only [Users’ Guide to TFS Aggregator](https://tfsaggregator.github.io/using/).